# Catch the executable call before running it

Tags: operating-system, registry, driver, executable

I am trying to develope something in windows that can catch the call of executive files before running it. The aim is to launch analyses on the executable and then execute it if the analyse is good or don't run it if the analyse is bad.

I have alrdeady tried to use the Register keys with the option "Debugger" to launch a different executable, but I don't know if there is a methode to generalise it to every executable files (except some importants) and i wasfacing some trouble with the rename of executable files...

I thought also to develop a Driver but this seems little bit long and hard so I want to be sure that a Driver can actually do my wishes (and if you know how to develop a Driver with only one computer, I would be happy to see your way :) )

So tell me what are you thinking? Have you some other way to do it or not? :)
Thank you for your time!!

Comment: OS developers are, understandably, reluctant to make such operations easy, (or even possible) - an alternative title might be 'how can I run my malware before any exe?'.

Comment: This is the opposite that i want to do, when a exe is called, I want to catch this call in order to analyse the exe before running it :)